# Evaluating the Macro value in java

Tags: java, macros

Take this scenario,

In string buffer i append string continuously  for example

```
 int a=10;
 sb.append("if("+a+">"+$b+"){\"checked\"}");
```

$b is a macro which assigned 
 finally based upon the condition satisfies string `"checked"` is added 
 how to evaluate the if condition because while evaluate `$b` value comes 
 as $b (which is finally replies as value) kindly help me.let me know 
 if you have any doubts.

```
  public static String getStringUsingMacro(String source,HashMap hm)
      throws Exception{
WebMacro wm = new WM();
Context context=wm.getContext();

Iterator it=hm.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    String key=(String)it.next();
    context.put(key,hm.get(key));
}


Template template2=new StringTemplate(wm.getBroker(),source);
template2.parse();
return template2.evaluateAsString(context);
}
```

Comment: I have read the question three times and I don't know what you are trying to do. ;)  Can you give some examples?

Comment: $b is webmacro it is based on webframe frame work i did not know about completely but in our project it may used.

Comment: @BALA: Java has no macros on its own. Please give **a lot** more context about the frameworks used to run this code.

Comment: In above code method getStringUsingMacro we pass the source (string) and hashmap having set of values based upon the values it replace $b to certain value i don't about this framework much that's  why i am not able to explain it clearly .sorry for all

Comment: @BALA: You should at least have mentioned that you are using the WebMacro framework here

Answer (score 0):

It appears what you are trying to do is

```
if(a > b) 
    sb.append("checked");
```

or if `b` is something calculated dynamically.

```
int a = 10;
Future<Integer> b =
if(a > b.get()) 
    sb.append("checked");
```

Comment: Future is one way of defining a value which is available later. (e.g in another thread) Another way is to use a Callable.